# How could a real world doomsday cult go about causing the apocalypse?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, apocalypse, weapon-mass-destruction, terrorism

This is not a fantasy or sci-fi scenario. This is about a doomsday cult terrorist organisation, akin to Aum Shinrikyo, in the present-day real world.

Is there any way that such an organisation with 10,000–60,000 members, and a \$500 million–\$1.6 billion budget (adjusted for inflation), could plausibly orchestrate and carry out a terrorist attack potent enough to achieve their desired result of an apocalypse scenario?

If so, how could they go about doing so -- using only science or technology, and restrained by their maximum budget, what's the most effective and deadly potential terrorist attack?

Comment: I wonder if a nuclear bomb coukd be used to set off a super volcano, set off even 2 of them at once and nuclear winter could ensue. But ive heard conflicting answers if nuclear winter alone is gaurunteed to kill all humans.

Comment: @ Seserous https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40936/could-i-intentionally-trigger-a-yellowstone-eruption . The top answer explains how that would not be possible, cetainly in this measly budget.

Comment: Most devastating in terms of property damage?  Lives lost?  What's your metric?

Comment: Thank you @P.Lord, that is why i posted coment rather than an answer

Comment: @P.Lord a tip: When you're responding to someone, don't keep spaces anywhere in the response ("@ P.Lord" doesn't notify the user, "@P.Lord" does.)

Comment: @P.Lord, what about nuclear shaped charges though? Plans for these have existed since the 1960's, and these are far more efficient in deep penetration than conventional nukes, directing 85% of their energy in an aimed direction. And there are other supervolcanoes with far shallower magma chambers than Yellowstone; Campi Flegrei's magma chamber, for instance, lies less than 2km below the surface. Along with others which are far more obscure, and more ideal for a terrorist attack which would rely upon total secrecy to have a hope of being carried out.

Comment: @Gryphon, let's use a banding system-

Comment: @Aquar1animal The problem is less the direction of the nuke more the fact that the most expensive nuke you can get with 1.6 billion is not setting off any supervolcanoes. Also can I please edit your post to add formatting?

Comment: Talking just about small volcanoes volcanologist  Erik Klemmeti said (about drilling holes to relieve pressure) it was like "trying to bleed to death with a needle prick". A nuclear shaped charge is essentially a really big hole. But a really big hole in a really big volcano is the same as a small hole in a small volcano

Comment: Band 1- property damage exceeding the budget, in excess of 0.001 percent (7,000) of the world population killed. Band 2- property damage of $10bn+, 70K+ fatalities. Band 3- property damage of $100bn+, 700K+ fatalities. Band 4- property damage of $1tn+, 7M+ (1 percent of world pop) killed. Band 5- $1tn+ property damage, 70M+ killed. Band 6- $10tn+ property damage (more than 10 percent of world economy), 700M+ killed. For reference, 9/11 was a Band 3/1 attack, on property damage and fatalities respectively. How much higher could these terrorists go?

Comment: BTW, what's with this weird formatting? Why's this happening?

Comment: @P.Lord, Aum Shinrikyo managed to embark upon its own nuclear weapons development program with the same budget, adjusted for inflation (or, rather, a far smaller one, since they spent most of their budget developing chemical and biological weapons instead), and they were purportedly successful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banjawarn_Station#Seismic_event  Why couldn't another group also manage to pull off the same feat, or go one better?

Comment: $300,000 was the estimated cost to make 1 bomb of 800 for the Orion spaceship. These 800 bombs would have been equivalent to a 10 megaton bomb. That's 240 million dollars for a 10 megaton bomb. If Yellowstone needs 460 tsar bombas that is 552 billion dollars. And that is assuming you have already got a steady supply of Uranium. Also you need to factor in the cost of land to build the land.

Comment: Which is it? A Doomsday Cult or a Terrorist Organization? They have very different goals. One is about the control of the leader, the other is about political change in a generally-unpopular direction. One is about power and control, the other is about logistics and messaging. If you're going to create some weird terrorist-doomsday-hybrid-cult, you must explain it's goals, resources, and internal structure in much more detail, or we'll mistake it for plain old crazy nihilism. Nihilists can't cooperate well, and groups without close cooperation can't cause an apocalypse.

Comment: @user537733, bringing in a post-apocalyptic dystopian society is an example of political change in a generally unpopular direction. The real world inspiration for this is Aum Shinrikyo, the Japanese organisation responsible for the Tokyo Subway Sarin Attacks (intended merely as a distraction to stop the police investigating its activities and searching its warehouses, which backfired big-time). Aum Shinrikyo was both a Doomsday Cult and a Terrorist Organization. And so is this group- their aim's to launch the mother of all terrorist attacks, to proactively bring about the apocalypse. Can they?

Comment: @Aquar1animal Disagree. Aum was purely a cult: It's goal was the leader's personal wealth and power over followers. Cults under threat sometimes lash out violently; that makes them criminals, not terrorists. An example of REAL terrorists: Red Brigades. Their goal was overthrow of the government by their preferred replacement. Big difference. This mistaken labeling of every violent criminal act as "terrorism" is a post-2001 thing. Don't fall into that semantic trap. The hybrid "terrorist-cult" concept is a nonsense built upon that semantic trap, like thinking "elephant seals" have trunks

Comment: @Aquar1animal "bringing in a post-apocalyptic dystopian society" is classic plain old crazy nihilism. Nihilist groups exist, and have never been a serious threat. They expend most of their energy on internal politics. Some mutate into cults, most just fuddle on as rather loose survivalist clubs.

Comment: @user535733, if you're launching a terrorist attack, then you're a terrorist organization. And if your organisation's actually planning an attack to try and proactively cause the apocalypse, as opposed to simply wringing your hands, crying "the end is nigh" and trying to con impressionable idiots into handing their money over like most doomsday cults do, then it's a terrorist organisation, plain and simple. But let's not argue semantics. The premise is that this is a doomsday cult whose leaders do seek to carry out such an attack, in hopes of bringing about the 'end of the world'. Can they?

Comment: @Aquar1animal your definition of "terrorist" is so vague as to seemingly encompass all violent criminal activity, so it's essentially meaningless. Cults with deliberately violent intent ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manson_Family)) tend to be discovered early and arrested before they can grow beyond minor criminality. Doomsday cults ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peoples_Temple)) tend to work much harder at deflecting police attention than a real doomsday, and big ones are often infiltrated by informants. But still can't tell what kind of cult you want.

Comment: @user535733 is it actually necessary to know the details of said cult? It seems to me that the question is whether a small group with a limited budget can create an apocalyptic situation that it not easily recovered from. The details of this group seem tangential here...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - the 'terrorist cult' is a lazy-writing trope, not a real thing, and the OP used a 'reality-check' tag.

Comment: @user535733 I still do not see how that justifies closure. Reality check means that science should be realistic. How is a group of people X attempting to cause an apocalyptic scenario unrealistic? People are capable of attempting. Whether or not they are capable of succeeding is the answer. What we happen to categorize them as seems completely irrelevant here and is purely an issue of terminology. Also if it doesn't exist then how is that also not an answer if that's what you claim? It certainly isn't a reason to close.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - why address to me? I did not vote for closure. But, er, that's not what the 'reality-check' tag says.

Comment: @user535733 you are the only user who has actually verbalized any lack of clarity so I can only assume that the users who did close are going off of your reasoning?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - a perhaps unwise assumption.

Comment: @user535733 well there are no other comments indicating a reason for closing as unclear so if that truly is not the reason than 5 people voted to close without bothering to leave an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

### Herbicidal Warfare

The best way I can think of is to kill crops.

Whether It is by mixing herbicides into fertiliser or releasing deadly diseases onto crops.

The world can protect against biological, chemical and conventional weapons on a full stomach but starve them and they are useless.

### More Typical Warfare

If this cannot easily be explained in your story then you could simply spend the money on a lab to mass produce either chemical weapons (Sarin Gas) or biological plagues (Smallpox).

These would then be released in all major cities (60000 people could do this) all at the same time.

The world will not be able to organise any relief effort as each city will be dealing with its own problems.

Biological makes more sense as it would then spread to the surrounding villages.

### Pigs

One more option would be to create a species of animals that emulates a plague.

Take the wild pig problem in Texas and other US states, pigs have been bred to be the ultimate ecosystem destroyers and eat tonnes of wild crops etc.

You spend your entire budget breeding pigs to be even faster breeders and even hungrier for crops.

Whilst also GMOing them so they cannot be killed easily through disease + poison.

Then you release maybe a couple thousand of these in Asia, Europe, Africa and America.

They become the Apex predator everywhere then start munching our crops.

We try kill them but there are too many.

It sounds silly but it is scientifically possible AND not even very far fetched.

Answer (score 2):

- You're talking about perhaps 3 divisions of troops, if all go to the frontline. That's less than the estimates of the [North Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_People%27s_Army_Special_Operation_Force) special forces. The budget would make them light infantry. Conventional warfare or even guerilla warfare are not going to be apocalyptic.
- Building nuclear weapons sounds not feasible, too. The [Manhattan Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project) used more people and budget than you have. Also, it had the backing of a government that could help with secrecy and so on.
- I think the doomsday cult has enough people and budget for biological warfare. Are their people suicidal? (There have been plenty of technothrillers on that basis, e.g. by [Tom Clancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Six_(novel)).)

Answer (score 2):

So if a cult were to go about taking over the world, I suggest you turn to the fictional world of comics. In the DC universe, there’s this cult called the League of Assassins. They have about 5,000-10,000 members, but managed to figure out a foolproof way to end the world. (Obviously that didn’t happen because.. superheroes).

**Biological Warfare**

First of all, you kidnap a group of scientists. They should be from all different areas of science, especially biology, chemistry, and technology. Maybe have one of the cult members who is good at stealth and is also a psychologist to scout for scientists that have a superiority complex, where they would do science without care of its result (i.e. the scientists who made the hydrogen bomb or the person - Alfred Nobel - who invented dynamite) and are also pretty lonely and mad scientist-ish.

Second of all, tell these scientists only the parts they need to know. Here the path splits. You can choose to go the hard way and threaten their friends and family. Or, you can brainwash them into being part of your cult, slowly recruiting them just like you recruit original cult members. Pay each a few million. That would probably be enough if your scouts chose them right. If the cult already has extremely skilled scientists, then more power to you. Tell then to develop a small disease that can kill an invasive species. Then give that disease strain to another scientist, and tell them to make it more powerful. (“It’s not working” or “There’s a stronger animal we’re trying to kill, it’s gone rogue.”

**After you have your disease**, make sure you have an antidote. Tell two groups of separate scientists to find an antidote, and either tell them that you’ll try it on them, or try it on some hapless prisoner this “cult” has captured. This might take some time, but…

Then choose some of the largest cities in the world. Los Angeles, New York, Chicago, Ottawa, Mexico City, Rio de Janeiro, London, Paris… these are all cities you could use. It would be easy. Have a few people let out the disease somewhere. Depending on the type, you can do it in a variety of ways. If it’s a solid, have them go to a popular buffet restaurant and discreetly drop the disease into a popular food. If it’s gas, let them gas it at a construction site or a vaping bar where the gas would be unnoticeable. If it’s a liquid, they could go to a coffee shop and pour the liquid into all the finished cups of coffee… (I’m never drinking Starbucks after this)

While this is happening, have the cult leader meet with some rich and corrupted people and tell them that you have the power to end the world. (*Don’t sound like a supervillain or an insane villain though*) Sell antidotes to a select amount of people, and the money you get can be used for “greater” things, like a regime or something. (I’m assuming they want to control the world).

Once the disease is released and there is worldwide panic, tell your computer scientists to hack into the global networking system and tell everyone that doomsday's coming. Depending on the goals of the cult, they can either tell people that if they join the cult, they might get an antidote, or that everyone is going to die, hurry up and panic.

And if the people in the cult want an apocalypse as in no one alive at all, then have the antidote actually be a slow acting poison (like some radioactive element) so they support your cause. And then if there are these hermits that never ever touched anyone for the past year and also has enough food to last for many years to come, either track them down or create a disease through plants that spreads like pollen and can also infect humans. Or just nuke the world after this with money from those billionaires...

And there you go, this cult just caused the end of the world. And *I was having way too much fun writing this for me to be sane*…

Claire